# Why does Chrome see SSL but not firefox or edge from AWS CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Here's my setup:

- S3 Bucket for static website. Site generated by [GatsbyJS](https://gatsbyjs.org)
- CloudFront Distribution
- Configured CloudFront alternate domain names for mydomain.com and [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- Attached SSL (from AWS Cert Manager) to my CloudFront distribution for mydomain.com and [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- Route53: A record mydomain.com to CloudFront domain
- Route53: CName record [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) to mydomain.com

Here's what I am experiencing

- mydomain.com: https good on Chrome, not on Firefox or Edge
- [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com): no https for Chrome, Firefox, or Edge

I'm sure I am doing something wrong with configuration with the 'www' part. The weirdest one is the Chrome vs the other browsers not recognizing the HTTPS

Comment: somewhat depends on what the SSL was certified for and whether or not the CA that certified it is in the trusted CA authority list for Firefox and Edge.

Comment: where did you get the ssl certificate. you can get one from AWS ACM for free. also i believe you created an `A record` as an `Alias` and point it to cloudfront

Comment: What do you mean by sees HTTPS? If you go to the HTTPS version of your domain it doesn't work on those browsers?

Comment: @ArunK, I got my SSL cert from ACM.
and yes, `A record` as an `alias` pointed to cloudfront

Comment: amazon ssl certificate should not have any trust issues. could be a browser cache issue. can you try from a different computer

Comment: @ArunK, tried on my phone (chrome, Firefox, and Duckduckgo). Chrome recognized SSL. Same goes for another PC. However, I then manually typed "https://" instead of just mydomain.com, SSL did work. For some reason, requests aren't automatically changing from http to https

Comment: Does your CloudFront or load balancer have configuration enabled to do this redirect or is this application side? Are you using a hsts header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try setting ViewerProtocolPolicy to 'redirect-to-https' under DefaultCacheBehavior on the Cloudfront distribution?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-defaultcachebehavior.html

Comment: Thanks! That was the one regarding http not redirecting to https